# Comparing adjacent elements in an array and selecting the smaller of each pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, break

I'm doing a JS algorithm course. Here is the instructor's solution for a problem, which is working successfully:

```js
function arrayPreviousLess(items) {
  const lessThanList = []

  for (let i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (let j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (items[i] > items[j]) {
        lessThanList.unshift(items[j])
        break
      } else if (j === 0) {
        lessThanList.unshift(-1)
      }
    }
  }

  return lessThanList
}


console.log(arrayPreviousLess([3, 5, 2, 4, 5]))
```

This code compares the adjacent array items. If the previous item is lesser than the next, it returns the lesser. In cause of false, it must return -1, like this example below:

input:

```
[3,5,2,4,5]
```

output:

```
[-1,3,-1,2,4]
```

I'm understanding everything, except what is the purpose to have `break` in the loop? When I deleted this `break` it worked the same way.

Comment: The algorithm is incorrect. Eg `[2, 4, 3]` should result in `[-1, 2, -1]` (since only adjacent elements should be compared, like you said) but returns `[-1, 2, 2]`. The nested loop is causing the trouble, and should be removed (instead, only compare indicies `i` against `i - i`). So it's hard to say why the `break` should exist, because that nested loop shouldn't exist at all

Comment: the "adjacent" should be emphasized. because if we remove that term, algorithm does stand: for an ith elem, compare it to all elems to its left and output -1 if it is lesser than everybody, or the first (hence the break) elem which is lesser than him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you've shown doesn't make much sense given the problem description of adjacent pairs. There's no reason for a nested loop in addition to `break` unless the intent is to compare each element to *all* of its previous elements, in which case it's correct. Either way, `unshift` is much slower than `push` and I see no reason to resort to this function regardless of the algorithm, nor do I see the reasoning behind the reversed outer loop.

I'd write the function for adjacent pairs using `map`. We can do this in one iteration.

```js
const arrayPreviousLess = a => a.map((e, i) => a[i-1] < e ? a[i-1] : -1);

[
  [3, 5, 2, 4, 5],
  [1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 1],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 1],
  [3, 2, 3],
  [3, 1, 6, 4, 5],
].forEach(e => console.log(`[${e}] => [${arrayPreviousLess(e)}]`));
```

On the other hand, if the problem is to compare each element against all elements to its left, I'd modify the instructor's solution to at least avoid `unshift` and traverse the parameter array from front to back.

```js
const arrayPreviousLess = a => a.map((e, i) => {
  while (i--) {
    if (a[i] < e) return a[i];
  }

  return -1;
});

[
  [3, 5, 2, 4, 5],
  [1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 1],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 1],
  [3, 2, 3],
  [3, 1, 6, 4, 5],
].forEach(e => console.log(`[${e}] => [${arrayPreviousLess(e)}]`));
```

This algorithm is still quadratic but there's a linear algorithm using a stack. For each element, while the stack isn't empty and the current element is smaller than the top of the stack, pop the stack. Eventually, the stack will either become empty or its top will contain the previous smaller element. Map the element to -1 if the stack became empty, else map the element to the previous smaller element. Finally, push the current element onto the stack.

```js
const arrayPreviousLess = a => {
  const stack = [];  
  return a.map(e => {
    while (stack.length && e < stack[stack.length-1]) {
      stack.pop();
    }

    return stack.push(e) > 1 ? stack[stack.length-2] : -1;
  });
};

[
  [3, 5, 2, 4, 5],
  [1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 1],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 1],
  [3, 2, 3],
  [3, 1, 6, 4, 5],
].forEach(e => console.log(`[${e}] => [${arrayPreviousLess(e)}]`));
```

The intuition behind this is that any previous elements behind the current element that are greater than it can never be previous smallest candidates. We can discard them. Essentially, we're keeping a history of smallest element candidates and dropping any as soon as we can guarantee we have some smaller element ahead of it.

Comment: Here is my own answer for this problem. Do you think my answer is accetable?

console.log(solution([3,5,2,4,5]))

function solution(inputArray) {
 const outputArray = []
 
 for(let i=0; i < inputArray.length; i++) { 
   if(inputArray[i] > inputArray[i-1]) {
    outputArray.push(inputArray[i-1]) 
   } else {
    outputArray.push(-1) 
   }
 }

 return outputArray
}

Comment: Yeah, that's a great solution and essentially the same as mine. Is it possible that you've misunderstood the problem statement? The instructor seems to be going for something totally different.